# Why Spring circular reference for Autowire issue on Production Environment Only?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, applicationcontext

**#All please read my question tiltle i already solve this**

Spring circular reference working on Local , UAT , DEMO , STAGGING environment But not on Production Environment only.
all environment having same configuration

> 1 JDK : 1.7.0.79
>
> 2.Tomcat 7.0

applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="in.test.server">
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="applicationProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:mail.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:document_storage.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:ekyc.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:application_config.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:messages.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:invitation_codes.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:capitalraise.properties</value>               
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:mail.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:application_config.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb_trunk" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="in.grex.server.datamodel" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
        <property name="username" value="${mail.mailAccount}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mail.mailAccountPassword}" />

        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailUtil" class="in.grex.server.common.util.MailUtil">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Bean for dozer mapper. -->
    <bean id="mapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper" scope="singleton">
        <property name="mappings">
            <list>
                <bean class="in.grex.server.dto.mapper.GrexDozerMapper" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- Bean for dozer searchmapper. -->
    <bean id="searchMapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper" scope="singleton">
        <property name="mappings">
            <list>
                <bean class="in.grex.server.dto.mapper.GrexDozerSearchMapper" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

**StackTrace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSearchService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.grex.server.dto.mapper.CustomGrexMapper in.grex.server.search.DataSearchServiceImpl.customGrexMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customGrexMapper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.grex.server.services.organizationassociation.OrganizationAssociationService in.grex.server.dto.mapper.CustomGrexMapperImpl.organizationAssociationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationAssociationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.grex.server.services.organization.OrganizationService in.grex.server.services.organizationassociation.OrganizationAssociationServiceImpl.organizationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationService': Bean with name 'organizationService' has been injected into other beans [utilityService,organizationUserService,companyService,messageService,investorService] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.grex.server.dto.mapper.CustomGrexMapper in.grex.server.search.DataSearchServiceImpl.customGrexMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customGrexMapper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.grex.server.services.organizationassociation.OrganizationAssociationService in.grex.server.dto.mapper.CustomGrexMapperImpl.organizationAssociationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationAssociationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.grex.server.services.organization.OrganizationService in.grex.server.services.organizationassociation.OrganizationAssociationServiceImpl.organizationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationService': Bean with name 'organizationService' has been injected into other beans [utilityService,organizationUserService,companyService,messageService,investorService] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customGrexMapper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.grex.server.services.organizationassociation.OrganizationAssociationService in.grex.server.dto.mapper.CustomGrexMapperImpl.organizationAssociationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationAssociationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.grex.server.services.organization.OrganizationService in.grex.server.services.organizationassociation.OrganizationAssociationServiceImpl.organizationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationService': Bean with name 'organizationService' has been injected into other beans [utilityService,organizationUserService,companyService,messageService,investorService] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.grex.server.services.organizationassociation.OrganizationAssociationService in.grex.server.dto.mapper.CustomGrexMapperImpl.organizationAssociationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationAssociationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.grex.server.services.organization.OrganizationService in.grex.server.services.organizationassociation.OrganizationAssociationServiceImpl.organizationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationService': Bean with name 'organizationService' has been injected into other beans [utilityService,organizationUserService,companyService,messageService,investorService] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationAssociationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.grex.server.services.organization.OrganizationService in.grex.server.services.organizationassociation.OrganizationAssociationServiceImpl.organizationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationService': Bean with name 'organizationService' has been injected into other beans [utilityService,organizationUserService,companyService,messageService,investorService] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private in.grex.server.services.organization.OrganizationService in.grex.server.services.organizationassociation.OrganizationAssociationServiceImpl.organizationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationService': Bean with name 'organizationService' has been injected into other beans [utilityService,organizationUserService,companyService,messageService,investorService] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationService': Bean with name 'organizationService' has been injected into other beans [utilityService,organizationUserService,companyService,messageService,investorService] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:548)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: Circular reference to WHAT? Show the complete error message/stack trace.

Comment: This needs a lote more informations. An empty context and vague descritpion doesn't help.

Comment: @trappski please check applocationContext.xml

Comment: @JimGarrison check StackTrace

Comment: If you read your own stacktrace, you'll see an issue with 'customGrexMapper'. I don't see any reference in your question about this bean.

Comment: @JérémieB why working on 4 different environment but not only Production ?

Comment: Please carefully read ALL the "caused by" exception messages. They contain suggestions on what to do.  As to why if fails in production but not other environments, CLEARLY production does not mirror EXACTLY the environment available in the deployment workflow systems.  Something is different in production.

Comment: #All please read my question tiltle i already solve this.

Comment: @trappski have u found any solution?

Comment: Well... The proper solution is to fix the circular dependency in the first place. It is obviously there even if it shows up only in one environment. Meaning you probably do have som difference in the configuration somewhere. And where are the beans in error defined? Can't find them in the posted context.

Comment: @trappski check this line <context:component-scan base-package="in.test.server">

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had exactly this problem a while ago. Spring is a bit random in the order it wires dependencies, so in some cases an application would start... and in production it would fail with this error.

The problem was a really bad practice promoted by spring until a year or two ago... the problem? Use setter / @Autowired on fields for injection rather than constructor injection. The issue we had, was that we were slowly migrating the configuration to constructor injection, and we opened ourselves to this issue, as we had a mix of the two. The issue depends on which bean is instantiated first. I cannot remember properly now, but I think that if the bean using constructor injection is instantiated first, the error would appear, but if bean using setter injection was instantiated first, the the error would happen. In this case, we should have done all of the work in one go. When everything uses constructor injection, the issue can be replicated in all environments.

The solution is simple: dependency cycles are a symptom of an issue with the design of the classes. You have to find what the cycle is and cut it. It's not a problem with Spring, but rather one within your application.

Answer (score 0):

Just now i have faced this issue and resolved by moving the required methods into one class and exposed it using @service annotation hence the issue has been resolved. This approach might be naive but solves the problem.

Class with all the methods/functions needed:

```
@ Service
public class Class1
{
    /% Method 1 %/
    /% Method 2 %/
    /% Method 3 %/
    /% Method 4 %/
}
```

Autowired Class 1.

```
public class Class2
{
    @ Autowired
    private Class1 class1;
    /% class1.Method1() %/
    /% class1.Method1() %/
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @Lazy annotation for constructor dependency injection.